# Конфиг-модуль для php

Tags: php, config

Подумалось мне как-то, что неплохо было бы сделать модуль для управления конфигами, чтоб можно было загрузить папочку по ftp, выставить пути-пароли и потом использовать в любых CMS/скриптах/приложениях. Чего бы от него хотелось: универсальность (хранение любых переменных), скорость, легкость, охраняемая "админка"-редактор, методы для изменения-сохранения. Т.к. поиск не обрадовал, а работы умельцев оставляют желать лучшего, решил заняться сам.

Вопросы, возникшие сразу:

1. в каком формате хранить конфиги? (нужны скорость и универсальность, абсолютна не важна редактируемость руками, потому это явно не ini и **ЯВНО** не xml, смотрю в сторону serialize, жду критику или одобрение)
2. есть у кого идеи для типа "значение функции"? Пока думаю сделать static массив, дабы при каждом доступе не плодить функции, а переменные задавать особым типом (см. приложение). Зачем? Например, для автоустановки путей. Как вариант - тупо eval'ить код (интересны аргументы за/против).
3. знает ли кто-нибудь штуку типа [winbinder](http://winbinder.org/), но более приятную в обращении? Хотелось бы для этого дела независимый редактор под форточки сделать, а парсер-сериализатор с нуля писать не совсем хочется =/
4. и вопрос явно опытным хакерам (в изначальном смысле) - как остановить парсинг и интерпретацию скрипта в определенном месте либо просто вставить в файл неисполняемую область? (см. приложение 2)

Приложение:

```
if (!in_array($function_id, $static_array))
  $static_array[$function_id] = create_function('', $function_code);
return $static_array[$function_id]();
```

Приложение 2:

```
<?
// исполняемая область
exit;
?>
неисполняемая область, набор случайных символов, 
в которой может встретиться "<?" или "<?php", а также 
непечатаемые символы (%00-%09 например)
есть ли способ где-то в районе "exit;" остановить парсинг,
чтобы этот файл отработал без ошибок? 
Без обработки неисполняемой области.
Может быть что-то связанное с HEREDOC, мне чутье подсказывает.
<?
// исполняемая область, ее можно исключить
?>
```

ЗЫ: если дело пойдет, естественно, поделюсь результатом)

**UPDATE:** радостный апдейт!) 4 вопрос решил сам. Если кому интересно, это задумка для php-sfx архивов. Если метку heredoc создавать из sha1(mt_rand(0, 100000).$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'еще куча переменных'), можно даже не запариваясь пихать архивы друг в друга. Кому задумка понравилась - пользуйтесь)

```
<?
if (!$f = fopen(__FILE__, 'rb')) die('Pls open read rights');
$CONTENT = '';
while (!feof($f) && (trim($s = fgets($f)) != '<<<PHPSFX8BAE970D3871669D96F9DF91C41735A14F8873A6')) {};
while (!feof($f) && (trim($s = fgets($f)) != 'PHPSFX8BAE970D3871669D96F9DF91C41735A14F8873A6;')) 
  $CONTENT .= $s;
fclose($f);
echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars($CONTENT).'</pre>';
echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents(__FILE__)).'</pre>';
exit;
<<<PHPSFX8BAE970D3871669D96F9DF91C41735A14F8873A6
?>aas das d<?asd $@#^@W SC GDG SDG Q@#% ! %@ @#% @# 
@#@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@<?ASDasdasd
PHPSFX8BAE970D3871669D96F9DF91C41735A14F8873A6;
?>
```

Это тестовый скрипт, демо [тут](http://sh4dow.jino.ru/test31.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для большего объема данных которые все время будут подгруджаться я использовал и использую JSON. У этого подхода есть свои достоинства и недостатки, но мне больше всего нравится простота обработка данных, конечно и с simpleXML больших проблем не возникает, но все равно все не настолько просто:

```
  $configData = json_decode(file_get_contents('filename.json'));
```

Serialize - лично я не одобряю, обосную это тем, что до сиих пор серилизация и десериализация в php реализованы не лучшим образом( кто не писал овер 2к строк кода на эту тему - лучше не спорьте =) )

С json'ом таких проблем обнаружено не было, да и, при необходимости - можно будет подгружать JSON конфиг в админке на редактирование ( накидать форматирование тут бы уже не составило бы труда и вот вам даже редактор, который, к тому-же, занимает очень мало кода как на сервере так и на клиенте )

По поводу exit - это столь принципиально использовать `exit` вместо `exit()`? =)

PS: сразу прошу прощения если где-то написал что-либо не в тему, просто, откровенно говоря, совсем не понял сути =) Но, тем не менее, что-то да посоветовал

---

upd

Как и раньше не понимаю сути, но если объем данных действительно большой и необходим действительно быстрый доступ - можно использовать базу данных и Engine Memory.

Тут, конечно, код не столь тривиальный ( надо как-то проверять не пустая ли таблица и если пустая - создавать ее по новой )

---

Скорость БД при таблице с engine memory(таблица хранится напрямую в оперативной памяти) не блещит?О_о

[[@Sh4dow](/users/465/sh4dow)](/users/465/sh4dow) - еще как блещит =)

Comment: и в переменную вернётся не массив, а ***stdClass object***
в то время как ***unserialize(file_get_contents($file));*** сразу вернёт массив данных.
А про сериализованные данные я написал, что конкретно будет зависеть от кол-ва параметров.

Comment: @Shrek с объектами, нормальные люди работать умеют так-же как и с массивами ;D

Более того (эта толька для тру) "избранные" умеют 1ой строкой преобразовать stdClass object в массив :DDD

Comment: Да эт понятно, я просто про кол-во действий, я же не пишу что JSON не тру вообще :)

Comment: ты думаешь что приведение типов тяжелое действие и хэш чем то принципильно отличается от stdClass object?

Учи матчасть =)

Comment: :P :P :P :P

Comment: json_decode(file_get_contents($file), **true**);

и вернется массив, учим матчасть.

Comment: Я с объектами привык работать и я (кагбы) тонко намекну - внутри json_decode происходит примерно тоже самое

Comment: при флаге true  :)


//UPD дальше не написать просто коммента.
Я и грю если флаг то да без флага нет :) в общем мы друг друга поняли, никто ничего против не имеет :)

Comment: естественно =)

Comment: @AlexWindHope большой толстый плюс за json, из адекватных вариантов он внезапно оказался быстрейшим. А вот база - не то, это надо еще конфиг для базы где-то хранить, а хотелось бы чтоб залил-распаковал-пользуешься. Скоростью БД опять же не блещет, особенно если каждое значение отдельно.

Про "exit;" - exit - не функция, а инструкция, потому скорее здесь скобки левые (ср. `echo('2'), require('tmp.php')`). В любом случае это лчные предпочтения, а я с дельфей начинал)

Comment: Принимаю) Мне это однозначно понравилось)

Answer (score 2):

1. Плоский массив сгенерированный через `var_export()`, либо сформированный руками. При наличии любого опкешера это будет наиболее быстрым и универсальным способом.

   ```
   <?php
   return array(
       'key1' => 'val1',
       'keyN' => 'valN',
   );
   ```
2. С учетом п.1 можно просто хранить замыкания. Хотя сама идея хранить в конфиге функции кажется мне, как минимум, странной.
3. -
4. Для этого существует специальная конструкция [`__halt_compiler()`](http://php.net/halt-compiler)

   ```
   <?php

   $fp = fopen(__FILE__, 'rb');
   fseek($fp, __COMPILER_HALT_OFFSET__);
   $content = stream_get_contents($fp);
   fclose($fp);

   // string(158) "Эти данные не будут парсится PHP,
   // в т.ч. теги <?php, переменные $someVar
   // или любые другие данные."
   var_dump($content);

   __halt_compiler();Эти данные не будут парсится PHP,
   в т.ч. теги <?php, переменные $someVar
   или любые другие данные.
   ```

Так же советую почитать про [Phar](http://php.net/phar)

PS

> `<<<PHPSFX8BAE970D3871669D96F9DF91C41735A14F8873A6`

Это не будет работать, т.к. в heredoc подставляются переменные. Однако вместо этого можно воспользоваться [nowdoc](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)

Comment: По п.1 - штука хорошая, но к сожалению по скорости она проиграла, `json:serialize:var_export` на массиве 50k значений и 10k итераций(собрать-разобрать) получилось отношение времени `1:1.2:3.4`. Да, я тоже удивился)

п.2 - у меня пока куча сайтов на php 5.0+, поэтому на 5.3 смотреть опасно. ну и с учетом п.1 нехорошо получится.

п.4 - вот за это огромное спасибо) Если не секрет, откуда такие знания? Вы документацию как сказку на ночь читаете или все же курсы-сертификаты?

И по поводу PS возражу - работать будет, т.к. участок стоит после **exit** и никогда не выполнится, проверил уже)

Comment: > штука хорошая, но к сожалению по скорости она проиграла

Экспорт переменных и не должен быстро работать. Да и зачем вам скорость экспорта? Вы же не по 100 раз в секунду будете его генерировать. А вот именно чтение при наличии опкешера будет максимально быстрым. Собственно он даже не будет читать сам файл, массив будет в памяти опкешера в виде байткода.

> Если не секрет, откуда такие знания?

Оттуда-же, откуда и у всех :) Опыт, php.net, google

> т.к. участок стоит после exit и никогда не выполнится

Согласен, exit не учел.

Comment: А вот друг в друга такие штуки с хальтом(п.4) не засунешь без обработки =/ грустно.

Answer (score 0):

Ну я бы смотрел в сторону сериализованных массивов + просто массивов.
Конкретнее будет зависеть от количества значений в конфиге.

XML явно неудобный формат для конфига.
Ini файлы еще куда не шло.

Можно для быстрого доступа сделать ini файл для разметки а внутри каждого раздела фигачить serialize массивы.